# adding leading / top constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I have the following code working for the height and width constraints. It crashes when trying to add the leading constraint and the top constraint. I have other sets of buttons that have height, width, leading, top constraints but they were all set up on the storyboard, so I figure these are the only 4 constraints I MUST add to each button.

I have 7 buttons, each for a day of the week. When I add the code to do the leading and top constraints it breaks with the error code below. It works fine with just height/width. I'm guessing it has to do with the way I'm adding subviews or the relationship of the buttons to the view controller OR when doing programmatically I need more than the 4 constraints (leading, top, width, height) I have been using on storyboard.

```
func setupWeekdayButtons() {
    self.weeklyButtons = [self.mondayButton, self.tuesdayButton, self.wednesdayButton, self.thursdayButton, self.fridayButton, self.saturdayButton, self.sundayButton]


    for i in 0...6 {
        print(i)

        self.weeklyButtons[i].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.weeklyButtons[i].setTitle(self.weekdayLabels[i], for: .normal)
        self.weeklyButtons[i].layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.weeklyButtons[i].titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.weeklyButtons[i].layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.weeklyButtons[i].layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
        self.weeklyButtons[i].setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        self.weeklyButtons[i].setTitleColor(.red, for: .selected)
        self.weeklyButtons[i].addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedDailyButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(self.weeklyButtons[i])

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self.weeklyButtons[i],
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 30
        )
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self.weeklyButtons[i],
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 30
        )
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self.weeklyButtons[i],
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 100
        )

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self.weeklyButtons[i],
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 100
        )
        self.weeklyButtons[i].addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        self.weeklyButtons[i].addConstraint(widthConstraint)
        self.weeklyButtons[i].addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
        self.weeklyButtons[i].addConstraint(topConstraint)
    }
}
```

> 2019-03-07 14:38:59.176638-0500
>   Daily[27852:1408014] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: 
>       When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
>
> 2019-03-07 14:38:59.177816-0500 Daily[27852:1408014] [LayoutConstraints] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
>       Constraint: 
>       Container hierarchy: 
>   >
>      | >
>       View not found in container hierarchy: >
>       That view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
>
> 2019-03-07 14:38:59.192176-0500 Daily[27852:1408014] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint: view:>'

Comment: What is `self` and `self.view`?  Is this code in a view controller?  What function in the view controller runs this code?  It appears that `self.view` has not been added to the view hierarchy. Also, your buttons will be on top of each other as they all have a leading constraint of 100. You might want to consider a horizontal stack view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>         self.weeklyButtons[i].addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
> ```

The constraint involves `weeklyButtons[i]` and `self.view`. If you use `addConstraint` to activate the constraint, you have to add the constraint to a common ancestor of the two views. That is what this error message is telling you:

> When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself).

Since `self.view` is the superview of `weeklyButtons[i]`, it counts as a common ancestor of the two views. So in this case, you can add the constraint to `self.view`:

```
self.view.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
```

**But don't do that.** Since iOS 8, you can activate a constraint directly, and UIKit will add it to the correct view automatically:

```
leadingConstraint.isActive = true
```

**But don't do that.** Since you are adding four constraints in succession, it may be slightly more efficient to activate the four constraints all at once like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    leadingConstraint,
    topConstraint,
    widthConstraint,
    heightConstraint])
```

**But don't do that.** Since iOS 9, there has been a much more readable way to create constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    self.weeklyButtons[i].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
    self.weeklyButtons[i].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
    self.weeklyButtons[i].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 100),
    self.weeklyButtons[i].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
    ])
```

**But don't do that.** Use a `for`/`in` loop instead of index variable `i`:

```
func setupWeekdayButtons() {
    weeklyButtons = [mondayButton, tuesdayButton, wednesdayButton, thursdayButton, fridayButton, saturdayButton, sundayButton]

    for (button, title) in zip(weeklyButtons, weekdayLabels) {
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .selected)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedDailyButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 100),
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            ])
    }
}
```

**Do that.**

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I won't be able to work on this until later tonight but I am sure this will help. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've added constraints in code, but if memory serves you have to add the views to the view hierarchy before adding constraints. (That's what the error message suggests.)

Comment: Your memory is correct, but that's not the problem in this case.